# assertThatThrownBy does not catch an exception

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am trying to test `underTest.createBookingGroup(...)` It cause the IllegalStateException if some income parameters is wrong. Here is my code for unit test:

```
    @Test
    void createBookingGroupWithOneTakenPlace() {
        BookingRequest booking = new BookingRequest();
        booking.setEnteringDate(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 7, 2, 12,0));
        booking.setLeavingDate(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 7, 10, 12,0));
        booking.setSourceFunding(SourceFunding.PUBLIC_INSURANCE);
        booking.setTypeOfBooking(TypeOfBooking.INDIVIDUAL);

        Set<Long> places = Stream.of(place1, place2, place3).map(Place::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        given(placeRepository.findById(place1.getId())).willReturn(Optional.of(place1));
        given(placeRepository.findById(place2.getId())).willReturn(Optional.of(place2));
        given(placeRepository.findById(place3.getId())).willReturn(Optional.of(place3));
        given(userRepository.findById(appUser.getId())).willReturn(Optional.of(appUser));
        given(companyRepository.findById(company.getId())).willReturn(Optional.of(company));
        given(bookingRepository.findByDateAndPlaceId(booking.getEnteringDate(),
                booking.getLeavingDate(),
                place1.getId())).willReturn(List.of(currentBooking));


        Booking booking1 = new Booking();
        booking1.setId(1000L);
        when(bookingRepository.save(any(Booking.class))).thenReturn(booking1);

        assertThatThrownBy(
                 // !! java.lang.IllegalStateException happens here 10000% !!
                () -> underTest.createBookingGroup(booking,
                appUser.getId(),
                company.getId(),
                null,
                places)
        ).isInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("The booking with entering date");


    }
```

The `underTest.createBookingGroup` with these parameters throws the exception 10000%, I tested it many times. But in a some reason I get the test fail. It looks like an exception throws before the code, it is very strange.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The booking with entering date 2022-07-02T12:00 and leaving date 2022-07-10T12:00 already taken by at least one booking with id:1
    at pro.dralex.Leo.booking.BookingService.checkAvailableDates(BookingService.java:81)
    at pro.dralex.Leo.booking.BookingService.createBooking(BookingService.java:106)
    at pro.dralex.Leo.booking.BookingService.createBookingGroup(BookingService.java:223)
    at pro.dralex.Leo.booking.BookingServiceTest.lambda$createBookingGroupWithOneTakenPlace$20(BookingServiceTest.java:623)
    at org.assertj.core.api.ThrowableAssert.catchThrowable(ThrowableAssert.java:63)
    at org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.catchThrowable(AssertionsForClassTypes.java:878)
    at org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchThrowable(Assertions.java:1337)
    at org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(Assertions.java:1181)
    at pro.dralex.Leo.booking.BookingServiceTest.createBookingGroupWithOneTakenPlace(BookingServiceTest.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at 
...

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting code to raise a throwable.

    at pro.dralex.Leo.booking.BookingServiceTest.createBookingGroupWithOneTakenPlace(BookingServiceTest.java:622)
...
```

Comment: apparently that doesn't throw said throwable

Comment: I have no idea, I tried to add ```throw Exception``` to the method signature - no effect

Comment: adding throw Exception to the method signature  would render the code uncompilable.

Comment: Check your imports. Is the `IllegalStateException` you're asserting to catch really a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`?

Comment: @ Petr Janeček Checked. It is not the reason.

Comment: Maybe the exception happens BEFORE but not IN the tested code...  I am going to discover it

Comment: So someone within `createBookingGroup` does a `printStackTrace()` but does not throw the exception at the caller

Comment: @Holger you are right sir. createBookingGroup exactly does printStackTrace() but not the exception! You can answer the question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For an exception to be detected by the `assertThatThrownBy` method, it must be thrown when the lambda is executed *and* the exception must reach the assertion method. In other words: if your code already catches and swallows the exception, it will never reach the assertion. Assertions can only detect *uncaught* exceptions, not any exception thrown anywhere.

Make sure that the exception is really thrown when executing the lambda and that it is not caught elsewhere before it bubbles up and that it can reach the assertion method.

It is for instance possible for your code to catch the exception and print its stack trace. That would explain why you are "seeing the exception", but it is in fact not reaching your assertion.

```java
void createBookingGroup(…) {
  try {
    // more code …
  } catch (final Exception ex) 
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```